# Нет перевода при обновлении фильтра

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, фильтрация-вопросов

Кнопка "Save or update custom filter" не переведена.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавил [перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/13025):

> Сохранить или обновить пользовательский фильтр