# Нет перевода текста после применения фильтров

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, фильтрация-вопросов

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тьфу... Всё-таки другой вопрос. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9644/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy да в целом про один и тот же функционал.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а еще не переведен title страницы, не не знаю, стоит ли для этого заводить вопрос. Также не совсем понял, что Вы исправили в вопросе?

Comment: @LexMarchenko скриншоты обычно в цитаты оборачиваем, чтоб не сливалось с текстом. Возможно стоит отредактировать более старый вопрос и там весь список слов держать, а этот закрыть как дубликат.

Comment: @Suvitruf, буду знать, спасибо большое:) А что касательно наполовину переведенного тайтла страницы? Там текст: "Custom filtered questions in my watched tags - Stack Overflow на русском". Как-то [так](https://imgur.com/6x1TOaz) выглядит.

Answer (score 1):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/string/11347

И для заголовка страницы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/string/13033